# How to make a submit button send data VIA SQL

Tags: php, sql

Code:

```
<fieldset>
                                <legend>Create Note</legend>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Information</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                       <input type="text" name= "Admin" placeholder="Your Usernme" />
                                       <input type="text" name= "Name" placeholder="Player Name" />
                                       <input type="text" name= "Note" placeholder="Notes" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-r-5"><?php $Data = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `SNOTES`(`Admin`, `User`, `Notes`) VALUES('Admin','Name','Note'"); ?>Submit</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>';
```

How would I get the submit button to send the 3 pieces of data to our SQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a piece of the html form code. It contains the "action" attribute somewhere before, which defines where the data will be sent. That MySQL insertion code belongs to that place of your PHP script, not to the form itself.

Here is an example: [Insert form data into MySQL database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429963/insert-form-data-into-mysql-database-table)